# Update CampaignMemberStatus for a Contact based on Opportunity Closure

Tags: apex, trigger, campaign-member

Currently I am using a campaign to track the status an offer sent to customers. These were sent to `Contacts` which are attached to an `Account`. Here's the tricky part: The `Opportunity` that is being used to track the offers are not related to the `Account`, but DO share naming conventions.

For example: `Account: ABCD-1234` / `contact@1234.com` is not related in SF to `Opportunity: ABCD-1234-Offer` / `contact@1234.com`

When the opportunity status changes from `Contract Sent` or `Not Started` TO `Closed Won` or `Closed Lost`, update that campaign member's status from `Sent` to `Responded`.

Is there a way I can update the campaign from the contact for a change in opportunity?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do:

1) Write trigger on OPP
2) When its close-won select Account by naming convention
3) From account select contact (there could be multiple contacts you will need to Select one for ex primary contact or most recently updated contact)
4)From contact select campaign member and update it

Few points to note:
1) You may get many records at point # 2,3,4 so you need to write selection logic
2) Bulkify your code and merge queries when ever possible for ex  2 & 3 or 3 or 4

**Edit 1**

AS SOQL does not support the inline string function we have following options:

1) Create formula field that gives you account name only

2) use like keyword. for ex.

3) Use apex

```
String s = opp.name;
s = s.left(s.length - 6);
List<Account> acc_list = [Select id, name from account where name = :s];
```

Comment: How would step 2 look in the query? If the Opportunity is firing off `Opportunity : ABCD-1234-Offer` is there a way to only select the account which matches the first 9 characters? I don't suppose `left($opportunity.name,9)` would work?

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from a programmatic solution, I am coming up with a declarative solution and I am hoping someone may look through it and point out any glaring errors I may have made:

In process builder-

Fire off `opportunity`;
Meets criteria (naming convention AND (closed won OR closed lost));
Immediate action - launch flow, pass variables `stage` & `account id`

Flow -
receive `stage` & `account id` variables
look up `contact` related to `account` **(this does not currently account for multiple contacts per account)**
update `campaignmember status = Responded`